# opencv open camera and ffmpeg open Microphone

Tags: opencv, ffmpeg, live

I use opencv open camera and obtain video and push stream. Then I want add audio and push it. When I use ffmpeg function

```
avformat_open_input(&ifmt_ctx, psDevName, ifmt, NULL),
program break.
```

So can I use opencv open camera and use ffmepg open Microphone?

I want to write anchor push streaming client and must use opencv open camera.